# android doesn't wait for .show() completion

Tags: android, jquery

I'm new to stack overflow and have a question about how show method works on android.

I expect that gray colored panel will cover on web interface when user click a button. Then, it will send a post request.

My code works as I expected on PC.
But it doesn't on android browser (firefox).

Could anyone kindly tell me where wrong is?
Also please let me know if you need more information to find out the solution.

Thank you in advance.

```js
$(function() {
 $('<div id=gray_panel class=gray_panel></div>').css({
  "background": "#999",
  "opacity": "0.5",
  "width": "100%",
  "height": 99999,
  "position": "fixed",
  "top": "0",
  "left": "0",
  "display": "none",
  "z-index": "150"
 }).appendTo($("body"));
});

function testBtn() {
  $( "#gray_panel" ).show();
  document.frm.submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="frm">
<button type="button" onclick="testBtn();">
 <img src="btn.png" alt="次へ">
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you calling show?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Kristy!

When user click the button, testBtn function will run.
Show method will be called as a part of it.

I forgot describing the difference of how my code work differently between PC and android.

On PC, submit method will run after gray_panel shows.
On android, submit method starts without waiting gray_panel showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for `show()` to complete and then submit the form:

```
function testBtn() {
  $( "#gray_panel" ).show("slow",function(){
      document.frm.submit();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your code.
I found out what’s wrong in my code today.

It turns out that one of the element had opacity and it affected badly when the code run on Android version of firefox.

Anyway, thanks for your answer!
I appriciated it!

Comment: @Norabal Did it work? If yes, please accept my answer.

Comment: The reason why show method didn't work was "opacity": "0.5".
Not related with "slow" argument.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.
The problem was...

`"opacity": "0.5",`

After I deleted it, everything started working properly.